# Acf icon picker

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I m using [ACF icon picker](https://github.com/houke/acf-icon-picker) with oxygen builder & acf

The issue is Oxygen Builder disables the theme completely.

I have tried this filter as mentioned on [ACF icon picker](https://github.com/houke/acf-icon-picker) but its not working

```
<?php

add_filter('acf_icon_path_suffix',
  function ( $path_suffix ) {
    return 'wp-content/plugins/assets/img/acf/'; // After assets folder you can define folder structure
  }
);
```

I have created a file with sub folders above but not sure why the filter is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found this on [ACF Forum](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-svg-icon-picker-frontend-php/)

```
// ACF ICON PICKER CONFIG

// modify the path to the icons directory
function acf_icon_path_suffix($path_suffix)
{
    return '/acf-icons/';
}
add_filter('acf_icon_path_suffix', 'acf_icon_path_suffix');
// modify the path to the above prefix
function acf_icon_path($path_suffix)
{
    return WP_CONTENT_DIR;
}
add_filter('acf_icon_path', 'acf_icon_path');

// modify the URL to the icons directory to display on the page
function acf_icon_url($path_suffix)
{
    return WP_CONTENT_URL;
}
add_filter('acf_icon_url', 'acf_icon_url');
```